# Query in python

Tags: python

I have a CSV file containing two columns. One has the IDs of employees and the second Column has their names. We need to write a program that takes the id as input and displays the corresponding name of the id holder.

```
import csv
fileo=open("id.csv",'r',newline='\n')
reader=csv.DictReader(fileo)
code=input ("enter last 3 digits of ur pincode -:")
code2="000000"+code   #to match the syntax
b=[]
for row in reader:
  b=row['id']
  print(b) 
 if code2==b:
   print("found")
```

In the above code, we are only taking the data at the first column (id). What happens is that it only does it once and stops when the condition is met.

Comment: Code as posted does not run because the `if` line is partially dedented and this is a SyntaxError.  Make sure posted code matches what you ran.  Remove IDLE from the title and tag this for `python`.  The IDE you use is irrelevant to this question.  Also, better to test code with data in the code.  In this case, a list of dicts would work.

Answer (score 0):

The if is badly indented.

```
import csv

code = input("Ingrese los últimos 3 dígitos de su código postal: ")
code2 = "000000" + code

with open("id.csv", "r", newline="") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    found = False

for row in reader:
    if row["id"] == code2:
        found = True
        break

if found:
    print("¡Founded!")
else:
    print("Not founded")
```

Comment: And that for loop can just be: `found = any(row['id'] == code2 for row in reader)`

Comment: Umm i think so, you can try that and if you get some problem comment that.